# How to ask the user to input a number then get the program to add up to the input starting at 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I was wondering how to ask the user to input a number then get the program to add up to the input starting at 2. I am currently using python 3.0. An Example on how i want it to sort of look:

User Input = `10`
List: `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: `l = [*range(2, int(input())+1)]`; but you'll need to think of how you might handle the case where  a user enters a string :-)

Comment: or just `list(range(2, int(input("whatever the user prompt is: ")) + 1)` because splats are ugly.

Comment: I love my splats, @AdamSmith

Comment: *somebody* has to ;)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def ask_num():
    list_of_num = []
    num = input("Enter integer number: ")
    try:
        num = int(num)
        for num in range(2, num + 1):
            list_of_num.append(num)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("You did not enter a integer.")
    print(list_of_num)
ask_num()
```

Comment: Yes, just don't use bare `except` clauses, catch `ValueError`s.

Comment: shouldn't the output be a list? Instead of printing statements